# I'm looking for Aviary Image Editor v2 file

Tags: javascript, image, aviary

I'm facing an issue with an old project. This project was using aviary image editor v2 which was hosted at https://dme0ih8comzn4.cloudfront.net/imaging/v2/editor.js. Recently this link stopped working. The main website is now not working due to this. If anyone has this library available or know any way to find it, please let me know. Thank you

I searched through the internet and was able to find the v3 version of the library. But v2 version is not available anywhere

Comment: [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20190402101758/http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v2/editor.js)?

Comment: I think this is it. But the total script is not there

Comment: maybe try a couple of dates from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/https://dme0ih8comzn4.cloudfront.net/imaging/v2/editor.js), also was that the only script you needed to include?

Comment: That script seems loading lot of other scripts also. Looks like It is a dead end